# Eclipse does not pass mail properties to Spring Boot after migration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I am migrating my Spring Boot application from version 1.5.7 to 2.0.0 and I noticed that it no longer takes mail properties from ENV variables for some reason.

I am using `java.mail.Sender` and have the following propeties in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.example.com
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
```

This is there just to mock the mail properties in tests. I am injecting the real ones using the same keys as ENV variables: `spring.mail.host=smtp.google.com`, etc.

But when I try to send the email, I see that it is still using `smtp.example.com`. I thought that ENV variables had higher priority than values from `application.properties`. Did something change? Everything worked fine in Spring Boot 1.5.7.

EDIT:
The following command works so it is definitely some problem with Eclipse:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development SPRING_MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME=xxx SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx ./gradlew clean bootRun
```

What I don't understand is why the exact same configuration works, when I switch back to 1.5.7. It is also strange that when passign env variables via Eclipse run configuration, it works for profile. So some env variables are applied and some not...

[image: Eclipse ENV variables]

Comment: I don't think that's changed in SpringBoot 2.0 - properties passed on the command line overwrite application.properties and the keys for those properties has not changed - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailProperties.java How do you pass the ENV properties to your app?

Comment: At this moment, I am passing them via eclipse environmental variables option which used to work in the previous Spring Boot version fine.

Comment: can you try command line so we rule out Eclipse as a factor? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Comment: It seems to be really a problem with Eclipse. But the behavior is very strange. I updated my question

Comment: @Smajl if you delete and create your eclipse workspace from scratch, do you still observe a difference between spring boot 1.5.x and spring boot 2?

Comment: @Smajl can you please post the configuration window from Eclipse in which you pass the ENV variables (with the variables filled in)?

Comment: @Smajl do you see in the Eclipse output/run screen the command line that gets executed when you run the application (does it have all the env variables present)? Have you tried to debug this and see what values are inside Spring's Environment?

Comment: I tried deleting my workspace and creating a new one with brand new lunch configuration and I still observe this same annoying behavior. Works when swtiching to version 1.5.7, does not work in version 2.0.0. Same configuration, just the version change. Works when launching from command line. aaargh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recreate this issue. Created a Spring boot App with 1.5.X and injected Environment variables from Eclipse. Now, when I migrate to 2.X release, the environment variables are not getting injected.

On further analysis, found out this interesting [thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1095)

One of the Spring-boot developers made this comment
[image]

Hence my conclusion is when we are using 2.X release, there is one of the component within Spring-boot-parent which is making the spring boot maven plugin to fork it and run in a separate JVM. Thus, the environment variable is not getting passed.

That answers the question why profile value is picked-up from the environment section. Profile flag is always passed as an argument irrespective of whether the app runs in the maven JVM or a new one

To confirm this, you can add the config entries to the JVM argument tab like the one below
[image]

You will now be able to see the new values passed to spring boot

Comment: Yes, that finally explains this  'mysterious' behavior! Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your configurations, but if the project structure is okay with correct dependencies and the application.properties exit under `src/main/resources` and your startup class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, it should work fine.

you can test if the application reads your properties file by injecting a variable String with annotation @Value inside any class and log or print it.

```
@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String host;
```

Comment: As expected, the result is `null`. As opposed to my other branch with version 1.5.7 where everything is injected correctly - with the exact same launch configuration.

Comment: Can you try run it out of eclipse? using the command line with maven "spring-boot:run" ,If it works, you may need to clean and import the project again inside eclipse

Comment: I already did that. It works fine outside of Eclipse and I recreated my workspace completely. I am not sure which temp eclipse files I missed out...

Comment: Great, if it works outside of eclipse, just do the following commands 

mvn clean install  then
mvn  eclipse:clean and later import the project as maven project

Comment: It is a gradle project but I will try to do the equivalent in Gradle

Comment: just clean the target folder and project files, and keep only the source code and resources manually if you cannot do that by commands.

Answer (score 0):

first Make sure your IDE is running on Java 8 or later version .

With Spring Boot 2.0, many configuration properties were renamed/removed and developers need to update their application.properties/application.yml accordingly. To help you with that, Spring Boot ships a new spring-boot-properties-migrator module. Once added as a dependency to your project, this will not only analyze your application’s environment and print diagnostics at startup, but also temporarily migrate properties at runtime for you. This is a must have during your application migration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")

**Note** Once you’re done with the migration, please make sure to remove this module from your project’s dependencies.

For more information follow this link

[Spring Boot 2.X migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is likely an Eclipse problem. I have already followed all the steps and migrated my application. Works fine outside ot Eclipse...